# How to Record RTSP Stream to Disk?

Tags: ip-camera, rtsp

I have an IP camera, and would like to record the RTSP stream to my hard drive in Windows 10.

How should I go about this? This needs to be a 24/7 running application.

I have tried ffmpeg, and this works, but is unreliable. I get errors about dropped packets and app abruptly ends under this scenario. Other times ffmpeg gives me errors saying it cannot connection using UDP, and tries TCP. At that point I have to reset the camera to get it working again.

I have also tried SharpRTSP, but the resulting video is patchy, and sometimes it can't connect to the camera on startup.

Couldn't get this working with vlc as none of the command line options I tried worked.

I have tried OZEKI Camera SDK and this often has problems connecting.

What is a reliable solution for this problem?

Comment: I have recorder RTSP with VLC, but from the GUI. Ref. http://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1023/~/saving-an-rtsp-stream-to-a-file

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting because that is basically the method I was using, but the command line equivalent. It just won't work for my case. I can stream it, but not save. I tried the steps in your link, and again, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

We can use openRTSP (A command line program ) program to store/record the RTSP streaming packet into the local folder.

Eg: Suppose, If we need to stream the IP camera through this application, then use the following command

## ./openRTSP rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.1:554/sample/media

note: "admin" is the username and passwords for some IP cameras.
syntax: rtsp://< ipaddress : port >/sample/media